# Modify from in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-mail

What if I want to use different email addresses depending on the relatedness of the form.

For example, I want to use `donotreply@domain.com` for my contact form. Then I want to use `myemail@domain.com` for my registration form. How can I implement this?

I've already tried to use the `from` method but didn't work. Please see my code below.

```
Mail::later(10,
    [],
    compact('inputs'),
    function($m) use ($email, $inputs){
        $m->from('myemail@domain.com', 'Name');
        $m->to($email)->subject($inputs['subject']);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I think

`compact('inputs')` will create an array with key 'inputs',better you should use `$inputs` instead of `compact('inputs')` as if

```
$input = [
    'subject' => 'some subject'
]
```

and using compact

```
$xyz = compact('inputs') will make it

[
    'inputs' => [
        'subjuect' => 'some subject'
    ]
]
```

**In Laravel 5.8**

In your mailable class for every mail type you can set different sender in build method like

```
class UserRegistered extends Mailable
{
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('myemail@domain.com')
                ->view('emails.users.registered');
    }
}
```

and

```
class CntactForSubmitted extends Mailable
{
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('donotreply@domain.com')
                ->view('emails.contact-form.submitted');
    }
}
```

Refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#configuring-the-sender)